# in bootstrap. how to do nav-tabs class to be only horizontally?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't want it to dropped below When it becomes a width of Mobile

I want it to be only horizontally

HTML

```
<div class="nav nav-pills nav-tabs nav-justified">

    <li class="active"><a href=''>Home</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href=''>link</a>
      </li>
    <li><a href=''>Link 2</a></li>

</div>
```

Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/mnzsov5z/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always just override the bootstrap styles with your custom ones. The only thing you would want to do is adding a new class that adds

```
display: table-cell;
width: 1%;
```

to the `.nav-tabsat>li` list element at all resolutions. see updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mnzsov5z/3/

Comment: Hi Moti. The text will get wrapped if the screen is too narrow. You can gain some space if you remove left and right padding from the anchors inside the pills. Something along these lines `.nav-tabs-honly>li>a { padding: 10px 0; }`. But to prevent text wrapping you would use `white-space: nowrap`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "nav-justified" is not supported by [bootstrap anymore](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified). Remove that and let me know if that works.